# How do I revert to default System.mdw after doing a SetDefaultWorkgroupFile?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am doing the following in code to set the default workgroup file:

Application.SetDefaultWorkgroupFile "c:\myworkgroup.mdw"

How do I find out what the current workgroup is before I do this so I can revert?  Is there something built into Access?

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a method or property to return the current workgroup file.  However, you can extract it from CurrentProject.Connection when you have a database open in Access.

```
Public Function CurrentWorkgroupFile() As String
    Dim strSplit1 As String
    strSplit1 = Split(CurrentProject.Connection, "System database=")(1)
    CurrentWorkgroupFile = Split(strSplit1, ";")(0)
End Function
```

**Edit**: I think the Split() function is available in Access versions starting with 2000.  If your Access version is older, you will need to extract the workgroup file location by another method.

**Edit2**: Read about **DBEngine.SystemDB** in the comments following this answer.

Comment: Er, is there some reason to not use DBEngine.SystemDB?

Comment: DBEngine.SystemDB is it.  Thanks!

Comment: There's some confusion in the question. The default workgroup file may be completely different from the one that is being used by a particular instance of Access. And even for an instance of Access using the default, changing the setting for the default workgroup file won't change the workgroup file being used in that instance of Access.

Comment: You need to catch up with me and get your Silver MS-ACCESS badge, so have some points!

Comment: I'll never tell! You'll have to find out yourself! I just got you one upvote closer...